# Unable to curl a variable that contains url of gif

Tags: linux, curl, jq

```
#! /bin/bash

key=LIVDSRZULELA #key provided by tenor
url="https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=$1&key=$key&limit=$2" 
#search key and total results will be given by command arguments

js=$(curl $url) # this have whole json result from tenor

res=$(echo $js | jq '.results[].media[].gif.url') # res contains the url of the gif that we searched
cd $HOME/Desktop/Me/gifs
echo $res # outputs correct URL
curl -O $res # this is giving error
```

problem is that I cant curl the res vaiable as its showing bad/illegal format kind of error

Comment: Always quote your variables.

Comment: If that's your real API key, you should blank it out here and change it at the site.

Comment: Pretty sure your curl is failing. What does $js contain?  Try assigning url as an array `url=("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=$1&key=$key&limit=$2") then call curl like this `js=$(curl "$url[@]")`

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer at `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable`

Comment: @rr0ss0rr Don't put a URL in backticks, you can't click on it.

Comment: @rr0ss0rr Why would putting it in an array make a difference? This is nothing like your related question.

Comment: @Barmar This doesn't seem to be a real/private API key. It is shown publicly in examples in their [Quickstart Guide](https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#quickstart-search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-r` to the jq command (for raw-output).  Your code can only handle `limit=1` The following worked for me

```
key=LIVDSRZULELA #key provided by tenor
url="https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=$1&key=$key&limit=$2" 
#search key and total results will be given by command arguments

url2=$(curl $url | jq -r '.results[].media[].gif.url') # this have whole json result from tenor
curl "$url2"
```

```
testit cake 1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4301    0  4301    0     0  37504      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 40196
```

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you for that. Can you tell me what was the purpose of -r flag in some easy to understand way

Comment: It will return just the data without any json-ism